# Springboot mongo exception with Docker

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker

I am new to docker and trying to connect a spring boot app with mongo db which is running on docker at port 27017. In my pom I have this:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I have not specified anything in application.properties. Below are logs from spring boot failure:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:67) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:579) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:549) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:339) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:603) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
```

And logs from mongodb(docker)

```
2020-05-30T00:31:55.387+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening on /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2020-05-30T00:31:55.388+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening on 0.0.0.0
2020-05-30T00:31:55.391+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] waiting for connections on port 27017
2020-05-30T00:31:55.405+0000 I  INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] index build: done building index _id_ on ns config.system.sessions
2020-05-30T00:31:55.425+0000 I  INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] index build: starting on config.system.sessions properties: { v: 2, key: { lastUse: 1 }, name: "lsidTTLIndex", ns: "config.system.sessions", expireAfterSeconds: 1800 } using method: Hybrid
2020-05-30T00:31:55.426+0000 I  INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] build may temporarily use up to 200 megabytes of RAM
2020-05-30T00:31:55.426+0000 I  INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] index build: collection scan done. scanned 0 total records in 0 seconds
2020-05-30T00:31:55.429+0000 I  INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] index build: inserted 0 keys from external sorter into index in 0 seconds
2020-05-30T00:31:55.431+0000 I  INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] index build: done building index lsidTTLIndex on ns config.system.sessions
2020-05-30T00:31:55.434+0000 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Marking collection config.transactions as collection version: <unsharded>
2020-05-30T00:31:56.006+0000 I  SHARDING [ftdc] Marking collection local.oplog.rs as collection version: <unsharded>
```

Can someone please help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you running the docker containers, could you specify the commands? typical error is you are not managing the networks as you should, for example you might trying to connect to localhost inside the container, thinking you are connecting to localhost as your machine and not the container.

Comment: Can you check the mentioned answers and see if it solves the problem and can be accepted as answer?

Comment: @nischay goyal I was able to resolve this issue by getting the Windows 2004 version upgrade and then installing Docker Desktop for Windows(after uninstalling the Docker Toolbox legacy one, which was required for previous windows versions). Not getting the error anymore.

Comment: That's great actually. shall i add this to answer and can you close it?

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by getting the Windows 2004 version upgrade and then installing Docker Desktop for Windows(after uninstalling the Docker Toolbox legacy one, which was required for previous windows versions).

Answer (score 1):

The solution to above problem:-

By getting the Windows 2004 version upgrade and then installing Docker Desktop for Windows(after uninstalling the Docker Toolbox legacy one, which was required for previous windows versions).

---

I would suggest you to run your containers via `docker-compose` and check the below `docker-compose.yml` for reference.

```
version: "3"
services:
  api-database:
    image: mongo:3.2.4
    container_name: "api-database"
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    command: --smallfiles
  api:
    image: XXXX
    ports:
      - XXXX:XXXX
    links:
      - api-database
```

Configure mongodb host name using spring config property using service name defined in docker-compose.

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=api-database
```

and then run

```
docker-compose up
```

> Ref:- https://nirajsonawane.github.io/2019/12/16/Spring-Boot-Mongodb-Docker-Compose/