# MongoDB on Docker Error: Marking collection config.transactions as collection version: <unsharded>

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm trying to configure MongoDB with Docker.
When I try to run my applications, I get this.
It stucks on trying to create a mongo server.

> mongo_1  | 2020-06-22T08:24:16.335+0000 I  SHARDING
> [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Marking collection config.transactions as
> collection version:

This is the last thing I get after several lines command.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Hi Maxbaruffato. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question and add configuration files. The better info about problem you provide, the easier it will be for someone to help you. Here are some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Springboot mongo exception with Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62096602/springboot-mongo-exception-with-docker)

Comment: nop that didn't resolve my problem :(